# Is there a way to retrieve the file in illustrator that just been accidentally replaced?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, history

Is there a way to retrieve the file in illustrator that just been accidentally replaced? is there some sort of history? The application was closed after it was replaced so there's no way i can undo it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only via  a backup solution. There's no method within Illustrator itself or provided by Adobe.

Answer (score 0):

**Sadly, no.** Undo is Illustrator's only way to walk you back to a previous version of a file.

Because designers so often work on similar revisions of their files, and overwriting your work is so easy, it's a really good idea to have software in place that tracks your file history. Here are some popular options:

- [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com/): The gold standard for fast, simple, feature-rich file sync
- [Google Drive](http://drive.google.com/): A lower-priced competitor to Dropbox
- [Pixelapse](https://www.pixelapse.com/) & [LayerVault](https://layervault.com/): Like Dropbox, but have revision & collaboration features oriented specifically towards designers

Presently, I'm learning [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), a GUI for [Git](http://git-scm.com/), which is a full-fledged version management system. That allows for annotating major versions, branching off features-in-progress to be merged into a codebase later, and things like that.

As designers, we put so much time into these fragile little files that I feel really nervous working on any file that's not secured by a file-history solution of some kind. Without some way to restore to a previous version, data-loss is not a question of "if" but "when" and "how bad".

Comment: mercurial may work better than git for large files. Anyway version controll is a must, baclup is a must versioning cloud store not so much.